# Validate Extension (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

```
<input type="file" id="css-file" />
<input type="text" id="css-url" value="eg. http://domain.com/style.css" />
```

I need both the fields to accept only .css files. Can I validate without having to use a validation plugin just for these 2 fields?

If anything other than .css is detected, it should give an alert()

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check th extension of both with a regex or [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) on the value, like this:

```
​$("form").submit(function(e) {
    $("#css-file, #css-url").each(function() {
        if(this.value.slice(-4) != ".css") {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(this.value + " is not a .css file");
        }
    });
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RVKPg/).

Comment: Hmm...possible to use onChange instead?

Comment: @Nimbuz - Correct, you can revert it if you *really* wanted to store/reverse the value...but I wouldn't from a UI standpoint. I'd put these 2 approaches together, warn on change, and don't let the form submit if it's not valid either...but I wouldn't change the input *for* the user.

Comment: I just added `$(this).val('');` after the alert line, should be fine I guess. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the value matches `/.css$/`.